# What is libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion() in my build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

In my build.sbt, I have this line.

```
libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % _)
libraryDependencies += "org.parboiled" %% "parboiled" % "2.1.0"
```

I can't remember what `the first line` means. How can I combine these 2 lines?

Comment: Sure would be great if SBT's [API docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.SettingKey) had bothered to document that method :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the later sbts, I am pretty sure from 0.13.x onwards, you can use

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value,
    "org.parboiled" %% "parboiled" % "2.1.0"
    )
```

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/More-About-Settings.html#Computing+a+value+based+on+other+keys%E2%80%99+values